# FactoryException when trying to create a "IconButton" in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I've tried to create an Icon that can be clicked, which means an Image with a ButtonBehavior.I followed the documentation (http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.html), and I've got a FactoryException with the following code:

```
# coding: utf-8

from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.core.image import Image
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder


kv_string = """
BoxLayout:
    IconButton
"""


class IconButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def on_press(self):
        print("on_press")


class DashboardApp(App):
    pass


Builder.load_string(kv_string)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    DashboardApp().run()
```

When I change the parent class of IconButton from (ButtonBehavior, Image) to (ButtonBehavior, Widget), the problem disappears.

Answer (score 1):

You want `kivy.uix.image`, not `kivy.core.image`.